# Access elements from a php file that isn't loaded

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have A main page called **index.php** where I have a link like the below

```
<a href="bedview.php" target="main" onclick="javascript:showHideBedsNurse('JimAndersson')">Filter Person</a>
```

where main is an iframe like below.

```
<div id="middle" >
    <iframe id="main" src="home.html">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The function called **showHideBedsNurse(Name)** looks like this

```
function showHideBedsNurse(Name){
        $('.bedclass').hide();
        alert("got Here");
}
```

Now to my question:  it displays the alert message I.E it executes the function but the function Can't access the elements in **bedview.php** (So no classes called **.bedclass** are found and hidden). I want to state in the function to load the page **bedview.php** with all classes called **.bedclass** to be hidden and in this case show all the classes **.JimAndersson** I.E the parameter called **Name**.

Is this doable in an easy way? I'm currently stuck. The function works if I execute the function in bedview.php but not as I said if I execute it when loading the bedview.php from index.php.

And no I **do not** want it to load bedview.php with .bedclass hidden as default, only when clicking on **this link** and execute the function

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Just curious. Why are you using an iframe instead of a div?

Comment: No need to use `javascript:` since... Netscape.

Comment: Not me that written the code, so I have to adapt to it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One would be to pass a variable to bedview.php, such as:

```
<a href="bedview.php?hide=JimAndersson" target="main">Filter Person</a>
```

Then grab the `hide` variable in bedview.php (that is, `$_GET['hide']`) and hide all elements matching its value (in this case, `JimAndersson`). You can do this by calling your `showHideBedsNurse` JavaScript function in bedview.php and passing it the value of `$_GET['hide']`:

```
<script>
    showHideBedsNurse("<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['hide']); ?>");
</script>
```

Keep in mind this is a very simple example just to show you the logic. Normally I wouldn't recommend mixing JS and PHP this way.

I'm also not clear on what exactly your `showHideBedsNurse` function does—what's the point of passing it a name if you don't use the name in the function?
You might want to rethink your approach entirely here. Look into using AJAX calls for this instead.

Comment: I am going to use it, just keept it simple thanks for the tip will try it out =)

Comment: Use `htmlentities` instead of `htmlspecialchars` if you really want it to be safe!